# C# 64 characters key

Tags: c#

I don't know C# but I have to do a update to a function that send a key to be encrypted.

I need to send a key with 64 characters, but the function that I have here only accepts 32 characters.

The function that initialize this process is:

```
Byte[] kkey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncKey);
```

What I have to do for this accept a 64 characteres key?

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` accepts any input length. You should really clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

The code you have included creates an array of type `Byte` which includes a number of elements matching whatever number of characters you provide in sEncKey.

It is my understanding that you are passing `kkey` to some function that will perform the encryption, and that this function only accepts a byte array of size 32. If this is correct, then you can't automatically increase the key size to 64 just by sending a longer key - it is the *function* you will have to change first, not it`s input.

Sound's like you're trying to increase security by using a larger key without replacing the lock first. Get a bigger lock first, then you can use a bigger key.

Also, if you need more help or guidance with this, you will need to provide info about the function, as well as some relevant code.